# Search string for tag text

Tags: php, regex

How can I search a string for a tag inside [ ] with parameters? So, for example, my string may have in it somewhere:

```
[tag id='1,2,5']
```

The numbers in the id parameter could be anything. I want to search to see if the tag is present and if so extract the numbers in the id paramter.

Comment: what you want is regex, short for regular expressions.  plenty of tutorials and references on a google search for 'php regex'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("~\[tag\s+id='([^']+)'\]~", $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

http://ideone.com/6b9JX